# How to stop downloading a streaming HLS video after navigating away from AVPlayer view?

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, avplayerlayer, avplayeritem

I am trying to play a HLS stream using AVPlayer. The player plays the stream fine, however, after navigating away from the player view, it does not seem to stop downloading data for the HLS stream. I see a network data spinner on the status bar for a few minutes after navigating away from the AVPlayer view.

I have tried `cancelPendingSeeks`, `cancelLoading`, and tried removing the `AVPlayerLayer` from its superlayer using `removeFromSuperLayer`, however, none of these seems to solve the issue — there is still a spinner on the status bar.

This spinner is seen on actual device, but there is no spinner on the simulator. I am certain the video is being downloaded; I can see the data usage in network monitoring apps. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Call `pause` on your `AVPlayer` object, then replace the item with a nil item, and set your video player to nil.

`[anAVPlayerObject pause];
[anAVPlayerObject replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
anAVPlayerObject = nil;`